# Chrome Omnibar sending unwanted request to my server when I mouseover the URL in dropdown list

Tags: google-chrome

Then it is sending the request a second time when I actually click on the URL or hit enter. How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: GET requests should be stateless.  Why is that a problem?

Comment: It triggers an oauth flow and at the end of that flow I save some stuff in my database. I can prevent any problems this might cause in my code, but that is beside the point. I just want to know if I can disable this feature.